# Tkinter window title shows invalid(????) characters

Tags: tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit, tkinter-layout

I am using tkinter for my application gui.The wm title command is not supporting utf-8 characters.

I have chinese/utf characters in my string and the same is passed to wm title function as shown below

```
set some_str "夹夹夹"
wm title . $some_str
```

But the windows title doesn't display the required characters (`夹夹夹`) and shows as (`????`).

How to resolve this issue so that the above utf/chinese characters are displayed in the title window ?

Comment: Works on my machine (macOS Catalina) in several configurations and several versions. What version of Tk are you using, and on what platform? I've got this vague memory that there used to be a bug on some platforms but not others; your code _should_ work, but it might be that an update is the easiest fix.

Comment: And the problem is _definitely_ an encoding issue — those `?` symbols are strongly indicative of that — we just need to pin down where it is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Read here, https://www.tcl.tk/doc/howto/i18n.html Chinese encoding in Tcl and also change windows region settings to china

```
set some_str "\u592a\u9177"
```

Comment: The issue was about tk window title name.This answer might not help me..thanks.

Comment: Use the method shown in this answer, do not embed utf-8 characters within your script.

Comment: @KawinAnto It seems to work fine for me (on windows). Just need to use the proper strings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5LRl.png